# vbscript that can install exe and msi on remote pc ×64 bit

Tags: vbscript

Can you please share a vbscript that can install exe and msi on remote pc ×64 bit

Also please share a script to collect hardware inventory i.e computer and Monitor serial number along with installed software for inventory preparations.

Thanks a lot Team.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the basics of querying for information. In `winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2` the `.` means current computer. Substitute the IP or server name for remote computers.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter where adaptertypeid=0")

For Each objItem in colItems
    Set Config = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")    
    For Each thing in Config
            Msgbox thing.ipaddress
    Next
Next
```

The command line equiv

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 nicconfig get /format:list
```

To start processes remotely (they are always invisible when remote)

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
intReturn = objProcess.Create("c:\windows\notepad", Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
Msgbox IntReturn & vbcrlf & intProcessID
```

And the command line equiv

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

Using the format on one IP address OR computer name without leading backslashes, eg

```
127.0.0.1
MyServer
```

`/node` can take a filename of computers and run the command on each computer, eg

```
wmic /node:@:C:\MyComputerList.txt" process call create "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

Type `wmic /?` for a list of common classes.

Comment: Please do not grace lazy, zero-effort, "write code for me" questions with an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's only useful to people that put the effort in to learn. It shows how to do similar things and one needs to read help to make it work. I call it a mini tutorial.